# Runaway cpu load on SGI machine in SGE

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

We're running oge 2011.11 on an sgi uv 2000 (smp) w 256 hyperthreaded cores (128 physical). When we run an openmp job on the system, it runs fine. Here's the job:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <math.h>
#include <omp.h>

using namespace std;

int main (
        int argc,
        char* argv[] ) {


#if _OPENMP
    // Show how many threads we have available
    int max_t = omp_get_max_threads();
    cout << "OpenMP using up to " << max_t << " threads" << endl;
#else
    cout << "!!!ERROR!!! Program not compiled for OpenMP" << endl;
    return -1;
#endif

    const long N = 115166;
    const long bytesRequested = N * N * sizeof(double);

    cout << "Allocating " << bytesRequested << " bytes for matrix" <<     endl;

    double* S = new double[ N * N ];

    if( NULL == S ) {
        cout << "!!!ERROR!!! Failed to allocate " << bytesRequested << "         bytes" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Entering main loop" << endl;

#pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
    for ( long i = 0; i < N - 1; i++ ) {
        for ( long j = i + 1; j < N; j++ ) {
#if _OPENMP
            int tid=omp_get_thread_num();
            if( 0 == i && 1 == j ) {
                int nThreads=omp_get_num_threads();
                cout << "OpenMP loop using " << nThreads << " threads" <<     endl;
            }
#endif

            S[ i * N + j ] = sqrt( i + j );
        }
    }

    cout << "Loop completed" << endl;
    delete S;
    return 0;
}
```

And here's it being executed:

[c++]$ ./OMPtest
OpenMP using up to 256 threads
Allocating 106105660448 bytes for matrix
Entering main loop
OpenMP loop using 256 threads
Loop completed

However, when I submit it in the queue using the following (and so far any) parallel environment, the load on the cpu shoots through the roof (well over 256), and the system becomes completely unresponsive and has to be power cycled. Here's my pe environment:

[c++]$ qconf -sp threaded
pe_name            threaded
slots              10000
user_lists         NONE
xuser_lists        NONE
start_proc_args    /bin/true
stop_proc_args     /bin/true
allocation_rule    $pe_slots
control_slaves     FALSE
job_is_first_task  TRUE
urgency_slots      min
accounting_summary TRUE

I've changed control_slaves, job_is_first_task, slots (reduced to under 140, anything over 140 and I get the runaway load condition previously described) I've even used different parallel environments that I've created. I've also reduced slot count in the queue to 140, yet the load still runs away and locks the machine. Lastly, I've tried numerous iterations, but here's my qsub script:

```
#!/bin/sh
#$ -cwd
#$ -q sgi-test
## email on a - abort, b - begin, e - end
#$ -m abe
#$ -M <email address>
#source ~/.bash_profile
## for this job, specifying the threaded environment w a "-" ensures the             max number of processors is used
#$ -pe threaded -
echo "slots = $NSLOTS"
export OMP_NUM_THREADS=$NSLOTS
echo "OMP_NUM_THREADS=$OMP_NUM_THREADS"
echo "Running on host=$HOSTNAME"
## memory resource request per thread, max 24 for 32 threads
#$ -l h_vmem=4G
##$ -V
##this environment variable setting is needed only for OpenMP-parallelized     applications
## finally! -- run your process
<path>/OMPtest
```

Lastly, since unlimited processors/slots have always crashed the mahcine, I've specified:

```
    #$ -pe threaded 139
```

Anything above 139 crashes the machine, yet there's no output in mcelog or /var/log/messages. Any insight into what could be happening would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Wow, no responses?? I get it, it's a tough one lol

Comment: Resolved it myself. Added the "-V" option in the script to push my environment variables out to oge/sge, as the job ran just fine in my environment outside of the scheduler. Ran every time with no crashes. Could track down the variable(s) causing the issue by process of elimination/trial and error, but I have a lot of variables. To sum up, "-V" fixes a lot of issues, especially if your job runs just fine outside of OGE/SGE.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it myself. Added the "-V" option in the script to push my environment variables out to oge/sge, as the job ran just fine in my environment outside of the scheduler. It ran every time with no crashes. Could track down the variable(s) causing the issue by process of elimination/trial and error, but I have a lot of variables. To sum up, "-V" fixes a lot of issues, especially if your job runs just fine outside of OGE/SGE.